# Exception calling "InsertBefore". The reference node is not a child of this node

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to insert a new node before an existing node using powershell but I am getting the following error:

> Exception calling "InsertBefore" with "2" argument(s): "The reference node is not a child of this node."

The structure of my XML document is

```xml
<config>
    <services>
        <serviceType1>
            <id>uniqueKey_1</id>
            <val>nonUniqueValue</val>
        </serviceType1>
        <serviceType1>
            <id>uniqueKey_2</id>
            <val>nonUniqueValue</val>
        </serviceType1>
        <serviceType2>
            <id>uniqueKey_4</id>
            <val>nonUniqueValue</val>
        </serviceType2>
        <serviceType2>
            <id>uniqueKey_5</id>
            <val>nonUniqueValue</val>
        </serviceType2>
    </services>
</config>
```

The XML document can have any number of serviceType1\2 nodes and the only way I have to identify them is via the id.

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

```xml
<config>
    <services>
        <serviceType1>
            <id>uniqueKey_1</id>
            <val>nonUniqueValue</val>
        </serviceType1>
        <serviceType1>
            <id>uniqueKey_2</id>
            <val>nonUniqueValue</val>
        </serviceType1>
        <serviceType1>
            <id>uniqueKey_3</id>
            <val>nonUniqueValue</val>
        </serviceType1>
        <serviceType2>
            <id>uniqueKey_4</id>
            <val>nonUniqueValue</val>
        </serviceType2>
        <serviceType2>
            <id>uniqueKey_5</id>
            <val>nonUniqueValue</val>
        </serviceType2>
    </services>
</config>
```

which is to insert another serviceType1 including it's child nodes immediately before the serviceType2 node that has the child id "uniqueKey_4".

Again, the only reference point I have is the id value.

The code I have is;

```bsh
$missingNode = "serviceType1"
$newElement = $myXMLDoc.CreateElement($missingNode) 
$myXMLDoc.DocumentElement.InsertBefore($newElement,$myXMLDoc.SelectSingleNode("//id[.='uniqueKey_4']").ParentNode)
```

I thought (incorrectly it would seem) that `SelectSingleNode(...).ParentNode` would give me a reference to the serviceType2 node via the id.

Comment: `serviceType2` is not a child node for `$myXMLDoc.DocumentElement`.

Answer (score 0):

What [@PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996787/powershell-exception-calling-insertbefore-the-reference-node-is-not-a-child#comment61547290_36996787) is trying to tell you is that you need to call the `InsertBefore()` method on the parent of the node before which you want to insert the new node. In your case that's not the `DocumentElement` node (i.e. `<config>`), but it's child node `<services>`.

Change your last statement to something like this:

```bsh
$myXMLDoc.DocumentElement.services.InsertBefore($newElement, $myXMLDoc.SelectSingleNode("//id[.='uniqueKey_4']").ParentNode)
```

or like this:

```bsh
$myXMLDoc.SelectSingleNode('//services').InsertBefore($newElement, $myXMLDoc.SelectSingleNode("//id[.='uniqueKey_4']").ParentNode)
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I think I've finally wrapped my head around how it's supposed to work now. Thanks folks.